# i want to call method every after every 5 minutes in background in android

Tags: android

hi friends in this task i have to call method after some time continueslly in background if i close the application than also call this method after define interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need anything ran after closing your application, it cannot be a thread that you started in your application, otherwise it would paradoxally mean that your application is not terminated yet.

You have to use a system service. The Android service you need to use is the `AlarmManager`. You'll find plenty of tutorials for it on Google.

Comment: The page must have changed. It's not mine anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It could be useful for your purpose: How to use a Handler to perform a task periodically [How to use a Handler to perform a task periodically](http://cart.kolix.de/?p=1438). It is more effective than using a traditional TimerTask. You can do this in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) so if you close the application, it will still occur.

Comment: so tell me please how to make service for this. have to make service using Broadcast Receiver???

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
private final Handler _handler = new Handler();
private static int DATA_INTERVAL = 5 * 60 * 1000;

private final Runnable getData = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        getDataFrame();
    }
};
private void getDataFrame() 
{
    _handler.postDelayed(getData, DATA_INTERVAL);
}
```

getDataFrame() will call every 5 minutes until you will not kill him `_handler.removeCallbacks(getData);`